# how remove spaces from a dataframe separated by ,

Tags: pandas

I have a column in my dataframe like this

```
    col
     An f,B k
   Af j , B
    Cd,d
   g c ,  k
```

how I can remove extra spaces and get this:

```
col
An f,B k
Af j,B
Cd,d
```

g c,k

Comment: use `df['col'].str.replace('\s+', '')` to replace blank space to ''

Comment: I have words, it is removing space from everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strip the beginning and end's spaces first, then replace spaces before or after comma,

```
obj = df['col'].str.strip().str.replace('\s*,\s*', ',', regex=True)
print(obj)

0    An f,B k
1      Af j,B
2        Cd,d
3       g c,k
Name: col, dtype: object
```